# Apache Ignite-Cassandra integration, data duplication?

Tags: database, cassandra, memcached, ignite

I'm planning to integrate the current Cassandra database with Apache ignite cache mechanism. Cassandra will act as the persistent store in that case. Database currently having Gigabytes of data.
Question is : Will this cause data duplication ? Does ignite store the existing data in its own schema for persistence ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common database caching use case. Ignite will be caching the data in memory for faster access, while Cassandra is going to be storing this data on disk. This is data caching, not data duplication.

Comment: So, ignite will be storing the "cached data" in the database right ? In terms of storage, how expensive will that be ?

Comment: I am not sure what are you calling "the database". If you are talking about SQL indexes, then yes, indexes will take up more space, but only for the indexed data, which is reasonable. If you don't use SQL indexes, then the only memory space occupied by Ignite is the cached data.

Comment: I'm referring ignite persistent store as database. In this case ,cassandra.

Comment: The data in Cassandra will remain as is. Ignite will not add additional data in addition to what you have right now. It will integrate with Cassandra in write-through and read-through fashion Does this make sense?